# How can I implement downloading files like those "click here if your download doesnt start in 5 seconds" pages?

Tags: php, download

I was tasked with implementing this type of downloading files, where you click a button or a link and a new page opens, and the download starts automatically, with the message "click here if your download doesn't start in 5 seconds".

I was told the file url would be injected into an iframe, and I have done that, adding a hidden iframe and set its src attribute to the file download url, but then, how to accomplish what those pages do?

Or, does that method of downloading files have a name I can google for?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh

Comment: thanks @Sammitch that takes care of the “5 seconds” timeout to start downloading, but how to implement the actual downloading?

Comment: maybe adding the iframe the meta refresh... I’ll try that, thanks

Comment: You don't need the iframe at all, just set the refresh url to the download url and the "click here" link to that url as well.

Comment: thanks, I'll try.. it's a WP site so it might be a bit harder than a simple PHP page